# How to make Windows WebStorm to import Linux Vue webpack project

Tags: vue.js, webstorm

I have installed WebStorm on my Windows desktop.

And I install Vue in Linux:

```
$ npm install -g vue-cli
$ vue init webpack vuedemo
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```

Is there any way to use WebStorm on Windows for editing vuedemo in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

You should better reinstall and run your npm package from Windows directly, along with your vuedemo. 
Main reason is because there might be some OS specific packages and commands set during installation via Linux.